# Forms within Bootstrap tabs not working/submitting

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm faced with a simple problem but just don't know how to solve it. I'm using twitter bootstrap's tabs. The tabs work but the forms within each tab don't submit. The forms submit when used without the tabs.

Below is the links I've used for the tabs

```
            <ul class="nav nav-list affix tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li>
                    <a href="#overview" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

And what follows are the tabs

```
        <div class="tab-content span9">
            <div id="overview" class="tab-pane" data-toggle="tab">
                <!-- Overview Forms go here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content span9">
            <div id="profile" class="tab-pane" data-toggle="tab">
                <!-- Profile Form go here -->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Finally I've added the following jquery

```
        $('.tabs').tab();    
        $('.tabs a[href="#profile"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: Hey everyone, figured it out, if you're having the same problem, you can easily solve it by removing the data-toggle attribute from the tab-pane e.g. `<div id="overview" class="tab-pane">` would be correct.

Comment: for me that was just to remove data-toggle="pill" ... almost same ! thks

Answer (score 0):

Same goes for bootstrap panels, when you have a form inside panel-body and try to submit the form nothing happens. You have to remove the "panel-collapse" class from the body :)